# how to get the last user Registered details from membership database and show in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, asp.net-membership

i am very novice in membership ..My manager wants me to display the details of last user registered  in membership database and show in gridview but i am not getting any method to do it..

I have created users with very basic details like username ,password and role name atc..

Now i want to show same thing over there in gridview.

I have tried with with the code..

```
GridView1.DataSource = Membership.GetAllUsers();
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

but it is fetching all records...

Is there any method in membership by which i can get those details...

Please help me..
thanks in advance...

Comment: you can get last registered user by created date.. make a query so that you can get the last registered user according to date and bind it with girdview